# How to source terraform module from different devops project

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have below scenario in my azure devops workspace.

I have project1 holding terraform modules under repo1/iac/terraform-modules

I need to use same module in another project named as project2.

How can I refer and configure this scenario in azure devops pipeline.

Both projects are in same organization.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create ssh key and add it to Azure DevOps under `SSH public keys`

Then store your private key in Azure Devops Library. It will allow you to install it using this step:

```
- task: InstallSSHKey@0
  displayName: 'Install terraform user git ssh key'
  inputs:
    knownHostsEntry: 'ssh.dev.azure.com'
    sshPublicKey: '$(TerraformUserPublicKey)'
    sshKeySecureFile: TerraformPrivKey
```

Then you can use terraform like

```
module "module" {
  source = "git::ssh://org-name@vs-ssh.visualstudio.com:22/ProjectName/_ssh/your path - here"
}
```

Path you will take from this place:

[image]

Here you have info how to create [ssh key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops)

In terms of known hosts please take a look on that note:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I understood your main file is in different Project and module have in different project and you want to give the source path in module file.

Solution you can use ssh key and PAT, below you can see the format and how to create PAT and ssh keys.

git::https://:dev.azure.com///_git///

git::ssh://git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3///_git///

[Use Personal Access Tokens to Authenticate](https://%20%20%20%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows)